Big Query - Get continuous 7 characters from a long string in Big Query
I need to look for 7 char long alphanumeric string that should always be in format of NNCCNNN, where N denotes Number, C Denotes Character and X denotes either a number or character.
For Example - For Car ID AB-CC-16TG842-ABA3864, ID should be 16TG842
For Car ID CD-CCIAL_50056956_15AD864, ID should be 15AD864
For Car ID FG-ENNNNN.OOPPLLI_PLOKI-17, ID should be Blank.
I tried using BYTE_LENGTH() and regex_extract() but couldn't get it as expected.
Could anyone help with this tricky one?

When posting a question, please consider providing all the clues/evidence/information you can.  For example, you said "I tied using ... regex_extract()" ... but didn't describe what you tried nor the result.

Sorry @Kolban the expression that i used was REGEXP_EXTRACT(car, r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+') as id

Ahh ... thanks for that.   That would find a sequence of characters ... 1 or more that were either "a-z", "A-Z" or "0-9".  There is no limit to length and not NNCCNNN.  Your thinking was solid on using REGEXP but looks like some more book time with Regexp expressions :-)

Thank you @Kolban for such a brief explanation..

Here is a direct solution to your puzzle:
with data as (
  SELECT "AB-CC-16TG842-ABA3864" as car UNION ALL
  SELECT "CD-CCIAL_50056956_15AD864" UNION ALL
  SELECT "FG-ENNNNN.OOPPLLI_PLOKI-17"
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(car, r"[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]") as id FROM data

It leverages REGEX_EXTRACT

I would go with more friendly/readable - REGEXP_EXTRACT(car, r"\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}")
